# Reformatting the output of eval in R

Tags: r, list, function, vector

I was wondering if there might be a smart way to make the output of `eval(x2)` become a `list` exactly like the output of `eval(x1)` without changing `x2`?

**P.S.** My ultimate goal is to achieve a function for this output reformatting.

```
x1 = list(dbinom(1:5, 5, .1), dbinom(1:7, 5, .1))

eval(x1)  ## this list format output is desired


x2 = c(dbinom(1:5, 5, .1), dbinom(1:7, 5, .1))

eval(x2)  ## can make this output to become like that of `eval(x1)`?
```

Comment: Why are you evaluating objects that are already evaluated? `eval` is not doing anything here.

Comment: It is not clear about the problem.  If it is string, then you need evaluation i.e. `eval(parse(text = sub("c", "list", 'c(dbinom(1:5, 5, .1), dbinom(1:7, 5, .1))')))`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can name the vector and then `split` ?

```
x2 <- c(a = dbinom(1:5, 5, .1), b = dbinom(1:7, 5, .1))
split(x2, substr(names(x2), 1, 1))

#$a
#     a1      a2      a3      a4      a5 
#0.32805 0.07290 0.00810 0.00045 0.00001 

#$b
#     b1      b2      b3      b4      b5      b6      b7 
#0.32805 0.07290 0.00810 0.00045 0.00001 0.00000 0.00000
```

Comment: The problem is we don't have the `x1` in real situations. So we should individually know what is each variable in `x2` i.e., `dbinom(1:5, 5, .1)` and `dbinom(1:7, 5, .1)` and then make a list of their output as a list?

Comment: @rnorouzian ohh..I see but then why use `c()` instead of `list` ? `list(dbinom(1:5, 5, .1), dbinom(1:7, 5, .1))` ? How do we identify when one gets over and the other starts ?

Comment: Is it possible to name the vector? Updated the answer above.